# Manage XML document

Tags: .net, xml

I can not find an easy way to do what I'm asking for.
I have an object:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And i want to:

1) Create the xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item Name="Item1"/>
  <Item Name="Item2"/>
</Items>
```

2) Read the xml document:

```
for each NodeT node in MyXMLDocument
{
    Item i = new Item(node);
}
```

3) Manage the xml document, for example delete Item1 and add Item3 (or change attribute value)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
  <Item Name="Item2"/>
  <Item Name="Item3"/>
</Items>
```

How can I do this as simply as possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML Serialization would be the easiest way in my view, although you have to sacrified `<items>` for `<ArrayOfItems>`

You can serialize your objects to a string, and then save them to a file:

```
string ToXml(object instance)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(instance.GetType());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(builder))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, instance);
        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Reading them back from XML to .NET objects just involves calling `Deserialize`. You can also customise your objects using attributes if you need, allowing you to choose how they appear in the XML.

Comment: @gliderkite you want to create an XML document and update it, surely doing this is with objects will be easier than manipulating the XML elements? Or have you got legacy XML to work with?

Comment: I have my data structure and i work with this, i want to serialize my data structure in a xml document. So i have to find a way to answer to my 3 questions.

Comment: @gliderkite you'll be reinventing a .NET api by writing the XML with XmlDocument etc. XmlSerialization is the fastest way

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to XML:

[MSDN - Linq to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)

[LINQ to XML](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24376/LINQ-to-XML)

Comment: Could you make me the 3 examples, as I asked, with Linq to XML?